# How do I mount this laptop harddrive using a Live CD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, mdadm

I have a Windows laptop that went wrong, and I would like to mount the harddrive using a live CD to rescue a couple of files.

I don't know how the drive is formatted or arranged but from my early understandings, looks like a RAID? ISW?

I want to run a live CD via USB - and look at the windows file system to rescue a couple files.

When I boot my live cd - my laptop harddrive doesnt show up in the 'other locations' of the file explorer.

Running `'lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL'` I can see my harddrive details as :

```
nvme0n1 isw_raid_member 476.9G
nvme1n1 isw_raid_member 27.3G
```

I have tried running :

```
'mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/nvme0n1'
```

and

```
'mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/nvme1n1'
```

both of which fail with:

```
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/nvme0n1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme0n1
mdadm: /dev/nvme0n1 has no superblock - assembly aborted.
```

Can somebody please help me mount this laptop's harddrive, in my live CD so I can explore it's filesystem!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is because the drive was encrypted using bitLocker - therefore mounting it and reading within a LiveCD is not possible.